# The Derivative of $f_{\psi, u, b}(x) := \psi(ux - b)$ w.r.t $x \in R^d$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

Consider the vector-valued function $f_{\psi, u, b} : R^d \to R$ of the form
$$
f_{\psi, u, b}(x) := \psi(ux - b)
$$
where $\psi: R \to R$, as well as $u \in R^d$ and $b \in R$, for any $x \in R^d$.

How to find the derivative of $f$ w.r.t $v \in R^d$?

Tnx.

---

**Reference.** Proposition 3's proof in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.02855.pdf

Comment: What is $v$ here? Do you mean derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$?

Comment: They mean the derivative with respect to $u$ (cf. the linked article).